# Vue.js test unit imports failing in spec files

Tags: vue.js, import, testunit

from a demo project, I can see that :

```
src
    components
        ShoppingList.spec.js
        ShoppingList.vue
    store
        __mocks__
            index.js
        index.js


ShoppingList.spec.js
    import { __creareMocks as createMocks } from "../store";
    ...
    jest.mock("../store");
```

this run without any problem, both imports are correct

========

I am trying to use it, but in my own project structure

```
src
    components
        ContactForm.vue
    store
        index.js
tests
    unit
        store
            __mocks__
                index.js
        ContactForm.spec.js

ContactForm.spec.js
    import { __creareMocks as createMocks } from "../store";
    ...
    jest.mock("../store");
```

both import are failing with Cannot find module '../store' from 'ContactForm.spec.js' error

Comment: you should check if there's store.js file in your test folder.

Comment: There is a __mocks__ directory with an index.js file in it ( as in the exaample)

Comment: your comment put me on the track !  the __mocks__ directory should be set in the src/store , and imported from there not from the test/unit

Comment: hah, just FYI, if next time there's some error like `can't find ...`, it's most likely the file is in the wrong place, and you should double check what default project from vue-cli provides you :)

Answer (score 0):

THe correct structure

```
src
    components
        ContactForm.vue
    store
        __mocks__
            index.js
        index.js
tests
    unit
        ContactForm.spec.js

ContactForm.spec.js
    import { __creareMocks as createMocks } from "@/store";
    ...
    jest.mock("@/store");
```